# How to increase the range of POSIX thread priorities?

Tags: pthreads, posix, thread-priority

I'd like to know how to increase the range of POSIX thread priorities beyond 1-99 for SCHED_RR. I've called sched_get_priority_min and sched_get_priority_max to verify the 1-99 range for SCHED_RR, but I'm porting code written for another operating system which uses more priority levels. I want each thread to have the same relative priority but do not want to force threads to share the same priority when they should be different.

Comment: Not quite - the app-to-be-ported uses more than 99 priority levels.

Comment: I've been through similar exercises, porting a product from VxWorks 5 (0-255) to Linux. I think that the task priority numbers are smoke - due to the differences in schedulers and context switching overhead, matching the numbers is meaningless. I even found that maintaining the same ORDER of priorities wasn't enough to avoid various new behaviours. Bottom line: you're asking the wrong question!

Answer (score 0):

You have probably read them already but the man pages seem clear enough:

> The  range  of  scheduling  priorities
>   may vary on other POSIX systems, thus
>   it is a good idea for portable
>   applications to use a virtual priority
>   range and map it to the interval given
>   by sched_get_priority_max() and
>   sched_get_priority_min(). POSIX.1-2001
>   requires a spread of  at least  32
>   between the maximum and the minimum
>   values for SCHED_FIFO and SCHED_RR.

I rather doubt there is a knob to twist to change this so my guess is you are stuck with either changing the kernel or scaling the priorities as suggested.  I frankly have to wonder if more than 99 priorities really amount to a hill of beans in actual performance.